# How to open an excel document using c#

Tags: c#, excel

I've used the [Open XML SDK 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=78bea298-a3f9-44cf-bde0-b4f30dc986df&displaylang=en) to create a new spreadhsheet and save to a users folder. i want to be able to open this automatically after saving. The file is in the xlsx format.

I tried

```
 SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, true);
```

This isn't working at all. I'd like the code to open the file in whatever version of excel the user has - 2003, 2007 and 2010 (Assumption: 2003 will have the compatibility pack installed)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If excel is set as the default viewer for xls files on the system you can open the file using [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("myFile.xls");
```

Answer (score 0):

This just opens the Excel for internal read/write in your app, but I assume you want to open it for the user in Excel?

Then you would have to do something like this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
       // A.
       // Open specified Word file.
       OpenMicrosoftWord(@"C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Gears.docx");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Open specified word document.
    /// </summary>
    static void OpenMicrosoftWord(string f)
    {
       ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
       startInfo.FileName = "WINWORD.EXE";
       startInfo.Arguments = f;
       Process.Start(startInfo);
    }
}
```

http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start

Comment: I guess, have not tried that. But this should only block the UI until word is started.

Comment: yeah, **UI blocked** unti _Word - Excel_ is started. Maybe is slower until the external program is opened. I have not found yet any **good patterns** about it in *Windows Forms/Console app*

Comment: Makes sense. You could try wrapping it into a Task