# How to open Excel file in app instead of downloading in browser using C#?

Tags: c#, closedxml

This is my code to download Excel file.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment ; filename=report.xlsx");
```

I want to open it in Excel.

Comment: winforms or webforms or mvc etc etc ?

Comment: Have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648347/how-to-open-an-excel-document-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Office Uri Schemas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/dn906146.aspx).

You can use in your html page a view command link like

```
<a href="ms-excel:ofv|u|http://contoso/Q4/budget.xls">Open in Excel</a>
```

These links work if office is installed on the computer (on mobile devices, too).